# Exporting all images in a Google Earth Engine image collection (Google Earth Engine API)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, google-code, google-earth-engine

I need to download a bunch of Landsat images for my thesis. My problem seems simple but I don't have a clue about JavaScript and the documentation didn't help enough.
I have filtered the collection to my region and time period and i want to export all images to Drive, seperately. 
Collection example:

```
var surfaceReflectanceL5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_SR');
var dateSR5=surfaceReflectanceL5.filterDate('1984-01-01', '1985-01-01');
var prSR5=dateSR5.filter(ee.Filter.eq('wrs_path', 182))
                     .filter(ee.Filter.eq('wrs_row', 35));
```

The code for exporting a single image is:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image1 //example, var image1='Landsat/....'
  description: 'L51984_1',
  scale: 30,
});
```

How can I iterate through the collection to export all images? The use of map() function seems to be the answer.

```
prSR5.map(Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image,
  description: 'L51984',
  scale: 30,
}));
```

The question is how to set the image parameter to the correct image (i.e first the 1st image, then the 2nd etc, something like '`thisImage()`' ) and the description to match image (i.e. `'L51984_1'`,`'L51984_2'`...).

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you're just downloading the images, I'd recommend using a more traditional source like [earthexplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) ... this will get you off of `JavaScript` and potentially be also faster and more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried ordering from earth explorer first but the order will take long to complete ( i assume a month as there are 200k images in backlog...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have created a function to perform a similar action. It is available in a bunch of gee tools I've created: https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor

Here is the code:

```
/* 
 * Author: Rodrigo E. Principe
 * License: Apache 2.0

PURPOSE:
This function Exports all images from one Collection
PARAMETERS:
col = collection that contains the images (ImageCollection) (not optional)
folder = the folder where images will go (str) (not optional)
scale = the pixel's scale (int) (optional) (defaults to 1000) (for Landsat use 30)
type = data type of the exported image (str) (option: "float", "byte", "int", "double") (optional) (defaults to "float")
nimg = number of images of the collection (can be greater than the actual number) (int) (optional) (defaults to 500)
maxPixels = max number of pixels to include in the image (int) (optional) (defults to 1e10)
region = the region where images are on (Geometry.LinearRing or Geometry.Polygon) (optional) (defaults to the image footprint)
Be careful with the region parameter. If the collection has images 
in different regions I suggest not to set that parameter
EXAMPLE:
ExportCol(myLandsatCol, "Landsat_imgs", 30)
*/

var ExportCol = function(col, folder, scale, type,
                         nimg, maxPixels, region) {
    type = type || "float";
    nimg = nimg || 500;
    scale = scale || 1000;
    maxPixels = maxPixels || 1e10;

    var colList = col.toList(nimg);
    var n = colList.size().getInfo();

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var img = ee.Image(colList.get(i));
      var id = img.id().getInfo();
      region = region || img.geometry().bounds().getInfo()["coordinates"];

      var imgtype = {"float":img.toFloat(), 
                     "byte":img.toByte(), 
                     "int":img.toInt(),
                     "double":img.toDouble()
                    }

      Export.image.toDrive({
        image:imgtype[type],
        description: id,
        folder: folder,
        fileNamePrefix: id,
        region: region,
        scale: scale,
        maxPixels: maxPixels})
    }
  }
```

I haven't tried it a lot, but worked in a couple of test I made, example:

```js
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

var col = ee.ImageCollection("LEDAPS/LE7_L1T_SR").filterDate("2002-01-01","2002-01-03");
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(col, "Folder", {scale:30});
```

If you have any issue you can comment here, but also you can post it on github.

Comment: I know that it is probably too late, but thank you!

Comment: if it worked for you, it's not late =) check this out: https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch

Comment: I was back then in a hurry, and totally forgot that I had asked the question and did not see the answer unfortunately till yesterday (2 years after :O).. The images covering my area were only 2-3 so I did it manually. But I will definitely use your tool in the future!

Comment: hi @RodrigoE.Principe , i tried copy pasting the test code you provided above but it doesn't seem to run on my google earth engine code editor :( i tried a few of the others you posted on different questions but none of them seemed to work. do you have any advice?

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried to download ERA5 data using the tool but did not work. Used something like this in the GEE editor: "batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(ERA5data, 'ERA5', {region: polygon});"
and also tried the python library using batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive which also didn't work. Is there any documentation on the library?

Comment: An important point is that Export is a client side function. You cannot iterate through the collection server side inside an ImageCollection.map() for example.