# export images in google earth engine en masse with two changes

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am gathering images for a large area in google-earth-engine (GEE) and would like to export them as one task with different names for each image based, this will be based on the location of each image.

I have a map of centroids covering the earth that I am using to define the scope of the images. The plan is to use this for the naming but that is out of scope for this question.

There will be two changing variables is the script, time and space. Preferably, I would be able to export them with all this relevant data in the name of the image all at once.

Is there a way of doing this without using the python library? This is to say, to do it completely server side?

I found this but this uses a for loop and GGE does not except for loops and the batch function doesn't show the ability for multiple vectors of change.

[Exporting all images in a Google Earth Engine image collection (Google Earth Engine API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868762/exporting-all-images-in-a-google-earth-engine-image-collection-google-earth-eng)

If there is a problem with this question, please let me know what it is.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid python? What do you mean "GGE does not except for loops"?

Comment: I would like to avoid python as it requires one to run a script on a configured machine and I am trying to make it such that that is not needed. GEE uses a custom iterate function and will not allow you to run for loops.

Comment: Well it does allow for loops, just not server side. `for (var i=0; i<10; i++) Export.image.toDrive(ee.Image(1));` works, for instance.