# How to fix "Invalid GeoJSON geometry" error in Google Earth Engine when trying to batch download?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am trying to use the batch repo provided by Rodrigo Principe that can export all images in a Google Earth Engine image collection using the GEE API:

https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch

He provides an example script at the end of this thread, which I have tried using but I get an error:

[Exporting all images in a Google Earth Engine image collection (Google Earth Engine API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868762/exporting-all-images-in-a-google-earth-engine-image-collection-google-earth-eng/44027855)

Error is:

```
Invalid GeoJSON geometry: [[[-73.87879425086899,46.471905677908346],[-70.84547603387989,46.471905677908346],[-70.84547603387989,48.4283626121078],[-73.87879425086899,48.4283626121078],[-73.87879425086899,46.471905677908346]]]
```

This problem persists whenever trying to use this batch tool to any of my scripts. The example script that Rodrigo provides is the script I have pasted below; I have changed the example image collection to something else.

What is frustrating is that I was able to make this work before, but now it is no longer working. Could there be some environment setting in the GEE API that I have accidentally changed?

I've tried using

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(col, "Folder",{scale:30});
```

around my scripts but I get the same Invalid GeoJSON geometry error for all of them.

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

var col = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR").filterDate("2002-01-01","2002-01-03");
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(col, "Folder", {scale:30});
```

When this works I am expecting to get all of these filtered images to individually pop up as a task for me to download onto my Google Drive.

Answer (score 2):

I'm certainly not a real expert on this, but I had the same problem today.

The workaround that I found is to set the region to the geometry bounds, rather than the coordinates field within those bounds.

So:

`region = img.geometry().bounds().getInfo();`

Instead of

`region = img.geometry().bounds().getInfo()["coordinates"];`

This seems to give me a reasonable output--hope this works for you as well.