# google earth engine- Sentienel 1 Download Image Colllection

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel1

I am trying to download availables scenes of sentinel 1-GRD into a date range. I have done this for a composite image and It has been worked properly but It is doesn´t work for an images collection.

My aim is to downnload all images GRD (VV + VH polarisation) into a given area (geometry). This is my code:

```
//
// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var imgVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'));

var desc = imgVV.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));
var asc = imgVV.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'));

var date = ee.Filter.date('2015-03-01', '2015-06-20');

var ascChange = ee.ImageCollection(asc.filter(date).filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon(geometry)));

Map.setCenter(3.3478, 39.6218, 12);
Map.addLayer(ascChange, {min: -25, max: 5}, 'Multi-T Mean ASC', true);

//print(ee.List([asChange]));

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ascChange,
  description:'Ascendente_CMillor',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry
})
```

ERROR:Multi-T Mean ASC: Layer error: Unknown variable references: [].
//

I think the problem should be when it tries to build the 'Multi-T Mean ASC' list of images but I do not know how to configure it in order to rename each scene with its *date* and *type of orbitProperties_pass* (ASC/DESC)

Finally, My idea is to obtain the results (images to download) renamed as scenedate_orbitProperties_pass_GRD.tiff

Can somebody help me?

Thanks,
Juanjo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to the way you're filtering the bounds of the ImageCollection. Instead, try using `.filterBounds(geometry)`.

Depending on your downstream usage of the exported imagery, you can export all images in the IC as individual images using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44027855/10656322) approach. Alternatively, you can export all images in the ImageCollection as one single multiband image with `.toBands()`.

```
// Mock geometry
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[3.2,39.5], [3.3,39.5], [3.3,39.7], [3.2,39.7], [3.2,39.5]])

// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var imgVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'));
var desc = imgVV.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));
var asc = imgVV.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'));

// Filter by date and geometry, create multiband image and clip to geometry
var ascChange = ee.ImageCollection(asc.filterDate('2015-03-01', '2015-06-20')).filterBounds(geometry).toBands().toFloat().clip(geometry)

Map.setCenter(3.3478, 39.6218, 12);
Map.addLayer(ascChange, {min: -25, max: 5}, 'Multi-T Mean ASC', true);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ascChange,
  description:'Ascendente_CMillor',
  fileNamePrefix: 'scenedate_orbitProperties_pass_GRD',
  scale: 10,
  region: geometry})
```

Comment: Thanks but I am still working on this code.

Comment: Thanks, very useful!